# Form Action PHP Sql

Tags: php, sql, forms

I have coding like this, it should when clicked Dekripsi button, it will appear download.php file, but this coding does not work

```
<?php
$nik = $_SESSION['nik'];
$no = 1;
$sql = "SELECT enkrip.Id, 
               (SELECT user.nama
                FROM user 
                WHERE user.nik=enkrip.filefrom) as nama,
               enkrip.filefrom, 
               enkrip.filename, 
               enkrip.kunci, 
               enkrip.dateupload, 
               enkrip.folder 
        FROM enkrip 
        WHERE enkrip.fileto = '$nik' 
        ORDER BY enkrip.Id ASC";
$data = mysql_query($sql);
while ($master = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
    ?>
    <form action="download.php?Id=<?php echo $master['Id']; ?>&file=<?php echo $master['folder']; ?>" method="post" target="_blank" >
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $no++; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $master['nama'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $master['filename'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $master['kunci'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $master['dateupload'] ?></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="kunci" placeholder="Masukan Kunci Dekrip"></td>
            <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Dekripsi</button></td>
        <tr>
    </form>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using method post for your form so:

```
   <form action="download.php" method="post" target="_blank" >
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $no++; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $master['nama'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $master['filename'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $master['kunci'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $master['dateupload'] ?></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="kunci" placeholder="Masukan Kunci Dekrip"></td>
            <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Dekripsi</button></td>
        <tr>
    <input type="hidden" name="Id" value="<?php echo $master['Id']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="file" value="<?php echo $master['folder']; ?>">

    </form>
```

All the parameters must be passed in post mode (using hidden input fields)